# Gif for Load more not displaying with Ajax and jQuery in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have followed this tutorial: [Rails - load more results using jquery ajax](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/rails-load-more-results-using-jquery-ajax) but not sure where I am making a mistake or if something in the tutorial is wrong.

**EDIT:**
<s>When i click "Load More": the ajax loader gif does not appear and the next 3 categories do not appear below the current 3 categories (with articles belonging to the category).</s>

When i click "Load More": the ajax loader gif does appear and the next 3 categories do get rendered. However, they are overlaying over the current categories instead of being added below the current categories.

**categories/index.html.erb**

```
<div class = "container">
  <%= render @categories %>
</div>

<div class="load-more-container">
    <%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif", style: "display:none;", class: "loading-gif" %>
    <%= link_to "Load More", categories_path, class: "load-more" %>
</div>

<script>
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
}); 
</script>
```

**_category.html.erb**

```
<div class="category" data-id="<%= category.id %>">
  <h3 class= "padding-bottom-20"><%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %></h3>
  <% div_id = "carousel_slider_#{category.id}" -%>
    <div id="<%= div_id -%>", class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="carousel-content">
            <%= render 'article', obj: category.articles.order("impressions_count DESC").limit(3) %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="carousel-content">
            <%= render 'article', obj: category.articles.order("impressions_count DESC").limit(3).offset(4) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#<%= div_id -%>" + "#{category.name}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#<%= div_id -%>" + "#{category.name}" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Categories controller**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:id]
      @categories = Category.order('created_at DESC').where('id < ?', params[:id]).limit(3)
    else
      @categories = Category.order('created_at DESC').limit(3)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

**assets/javascripts/category.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.load-more').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.load-more').hide();
        $('.loading-gif').show();

        var last_id = $('.category').last().attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            data: {
                id: last_id
            },
            dataType: "script",

            success: function () {
                $('.loading-gif').hide();
                $('.load-more').show();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**categories/index.js.erb**

```
$('.container').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @categories)) %>')
```

Comment: If you vote to close this at least explain why. This new user has put in sufficient effort. Try to add value by asking questions or helping with relevant edits rather than just trying to shut down new users.

Comment: Any hint in the network tab?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I have checked and the next 3 categories are being rendered, but seem to be overlayed instead of being appended below.

Comment: Try wrapping the content of your _category partial in a `.row` div.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i managed to fix it by wrapping a div id (div id="category" instead of a div class="container", and adjusted the index.js.erb accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Change index.html.erb to

```
<div id="category">
  <%= render @categories %>
</div>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#category').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: @categories)) %>')
```